# Common Unique Id between revit and forge document

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, forge

We were using **Revit Project Information** as **Unique Id** between the revit and forge document. But as checked the **Revit Project Information Unique Id** came same for two distinct file. Is there any other **Unique Id between revit and forge document which is common and distinct**?

Comment: Supposing your RVT files are file A & file B. If file B is copied from file A (or inverted), the `Revit Project Information Unique Id` will be the same, since they are the same file despite their filenames are different.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [`GetProjectId` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/902d5aa9-9f3f-a9e9-0d0a-4c95fa820890.htm) will fulfil your requirements. It returns a ForgeDM project id where the model is located. It is empty for a non-cloud model; it is cached in the Revit model opened session after getting it.

Before the advent of that, I implemented my own [Named Guid Storage for Project Identification](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/04/named-guid-storage-for-project-identification.html) to address this requirement.

You might even want to combine my DIY solution with other approaches.